# Conditional probability distributions

Tags: probability

How can one quantify the probability of drawing 4 different balls with replacement from a universe of 8 different balls

Answer (score 1):

Each draw is an independent random event, the odds of picking a unique balls is dependent on the number of previous picks.

- First draw 8/8 or 100% of drawing a unique ball
- Second draw is 7 out of 8 of drawing a unique ball (8 - 1 previous draw)
- Third draw is 6 out of 8  (8 - 2 previous draws)
- The fourth and final draw is 5 out of 8 (8 - 3 previous draws)

So the overall chance of success is 8/8 * 7/8 * 6/8 * 5/8 or 210/(8^3) or about 41% chance of drawing 4 different balls out of 8 with replacement.